# Angular HttpClient Behavior Raw HTML

Tags: angular, httpclient, spotify

I'm using Angular 5 HttpClient and I'm trying to get an HTML response from a page that provides both json data and HTML. (Spotify auth).

When I curl, I get the expected HTML and the json payload. No matter what I try with HttpClient, all I can get is the json, which in this case is not helpful. I want to get to the HTML. I have verified my headers are identically between the command line curl and the HttpClient.

```
curl -vvv https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx81ad8fc&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://reaver.xxxxxx.com:4200/callback&state=34fFs29kd09

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="accounts" ng-csp>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title ng-bind="(title && (title | localize) + ' - ') + 'Spotify'">Spotify</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <base href="/">
    <link href="https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/a4a5157/css/index.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">

    <script async defer src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/a4a5157/js/index.js" sp-bootstrap></script>
    <meta ng-non-bindable sp-bootstrap-data='{"client":{"name":"Playlist Reaver"},"country":"US","useCaptcha":false,"locales":["*"],"BON":["0","0",-795429514]}'>
  </head>
  <body ng-view></body>
</html>
```

This part of that payload is all I can get HttpClient to expose to me.

```
{"client":{"name":"Playlist Reaver"},"country":"US","useCaptcha":false,"locales":["*"],"BON":["0","0",-795429514]}
```

Which normally I would say great, but I really need access to the HTML.

How do I get the raw html back from a response like this that contains both json data and HTML?

My get call looks like this:

```
return this.http.get(this.apiGeneric, { params: params, observe: 'response'});
```

Additional info: My http headers do not appear to be added. I have made the following change and I see no XFF header in the http request headers.

```
  // function returns Observable UserResponse object
  getUrl() {
    this.httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    //.set('Content-Type'
    this.httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8');
    this.httpHeaders.set('XFF', 'testing123');

    let params = new HttpParams();
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('client_id', this.clientId)
      .set('response_type', 'code')
      .set('redirect_uri', this.redirectUri)

    console.log(params);
    return this.http.get(this.apiGeneric, { headers: this.httpHeaders, params: params, observe: 'response' });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting an appropriate accept type?

Comment: try using { params: params, observe: 'response', responseType: 'text'}

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. I did actually:

this.httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'text/html');

Chrome developer mode captured this as the header being sent:

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

Comment: @david Thanks. Once I got the right headers to the api and was getting the HTML and other payloads back, then I was getting json decode errors and the responseType helped turn off the json decoding. All set thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the issue. This is probably something I misunderstood about generating headers, but what I found was that:

```
this.httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
this.httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8');
```

(Both .set and .add) would result in an empty httpHeaders

Changing how I constructed the header solved my problem and the content-type header (And some customer test headers) were inserted and I got the full HTML output. If anyone else runs into this, here is the proper way to construct a header that solved my problem:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    Accept:'text/html',
    XFF:'testing123'
  });

const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('client_id', this.clientId)
  .set('response_type', 'code')
  .set('redirect_uri', this.redirectUri)

console.log(headers.get('Accept'));
console.log(this.apiGeneric);
return this.http.get(this.apiGeneric, { headers: headers, params:params });
}
```

Evidence:XFF Header and Accept headers are what we set them to:

```
Accept:text/html
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Host:accounts.spotify.com
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://192.168.1.29:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
XFF:testing123
```

Comment: `HttpHeaders` objects are *immutable*; `.set` and `.add` return a new object with that additional header. Hence chaining, or setting `this.httpHeaders = this.httpHeaders.set(...);`, works.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. That was of course my misunderstanding. Now I understand perfectly. Thanks again!